# How to create a button in .ts file in angular and add click event

Tags: html, angular, events, button, onclick

I want to create a button in typescript file using the html tags.I don't know how to add click event for that button 
i have created 2 action buttons wat to add the click event

```
"data": "img", "render": function (data) {
    return '<button class="btn tblActnBtn" value= "Click" id="edit" (click)="onClickMe()" ><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></button><button class="btn tblActnBtn"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button>'
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you creating a button it `.ts` and not in `.html`? You can change the value with interpolation. 
Please describe carefully your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
self.testTable.on('click', 'input', function () {

  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

  var row = self.testTable.row(tr);

  var id = this.id;

  var data = self.testTable.row(tr).data();

  if (id == 'check') {

   console.log("****",row.data())

  }

});
```

It works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

html :

```
<div  [innerHTML]="answerPanelContent"></div>
```

ts:

```
import { Component, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  constructor(    private renderer:Renderer2,
                  private el:ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const button = this.renderer.createElement('button');
    const buttonText = this.renderer.createText('Click me');
    this.renderer.appendChild(button, buttonText);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, button);
    this.renderer.listen(button, 'click', () => {alert('hi');});
  }
}
```

you can write every event in {alert('hi');......}